# How to track-back an invitation in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, tracking, invitation

I've been invited to Facebook. After following the link I see the photograph of who has made the invitation when logged-off but upon logging-in I cannot find or track him. I've tried the link on his name from email but Facebook doesn't show me anything related to him (even in suggestions).

Is it possible who is invisible to me invite me?

I mean he has some sort of settings on his profile that prevent me to find his page. The name used in invitation is so general which leads to days of searching Facebook to recognize him from invitation photo (if visible from search which I doubt).

How can I track-back who has made this invitation?

Could it be an automated invitation without awareness of somebody who has my email in his Facebook account or I can consider it intended by some person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not missing something, before logging-in (registering) to Facebook, you was able to see that person's profile photo *only* and no other data or details. Am I right.

Situation, you're describing *may be possibly* coming from the fact, that anyone's Facebook profile photo is always public, no matter what. So, the person, that invited you to Facebook may set it's account settings, that everything (including entire page) is visible only to its friends. This way, you see his or her photo, when you're logged-off Facebook and see completely nothing, when you're logged-in (unless you accept or send and have accepted your Friends Request to that person).

This is a little bit strange, but not impossible in Facebook.

As for your second part. Yes, this could be an effect of someone's invitation without awareness. When you add a large number of e-mails to Facebook Friends Finder (either by uploading list from file or giving Facebook's access to your mailbox) it prepares list of all e-mails in your list that has Facebook account connected to it. It then presents you this with a checkboxesand allows you to uncheck some.

But... answer yourself, would you care for something like that? Most people just pass by to the next step, sending invitations to anyone from their e-mails list, that has Facebook account. This is a little bit tricky (or even stupid), especially, when you take a strong false-friends Facebook politics (if too many people click that they don't know you, upon your Friends Request, you may be blocked from sending these requests, have to verify your personality or even have your entire account blocked).

But the reality is, that it works like it works and both Facebook and the entire Internet are every day simply bloated with false-friends invitation without awareness.